# CSS layout/grid not align

Tags: html, css, layout

I do not understand why my right column's width is not match with my right menu and center information. I have tried putting a float around each individual element to make a three column grid. Floats for left, center, and right are used to position the columns to create the structure of the three column. However, the last column (right column) width is not aligned with the other two column. There should be enough space for the third column to align with the rest of the columns. Please advise. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scal=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" title="Style 1" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <title>somepage</title>
</head> 
    <body>
    <h1>somepage</h1>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center_grid">
    <div id="select_color">


    </div>
    <div id="my_color">
        <h2>my Colors</h2>
        <p>start off with some color.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_grid">
    <div id="help">
        <h2>Help</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.left_grid {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.center_grid {
    float: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 20em;
    margin-right: 20em;
}
.right_grid {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#menu {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 10em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
#select_color {

    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 2em;

}
#predefined_color {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
#help {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 10em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
According to your problem and responsive middle column, please use this code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scal=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" title="Style 1" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <title>somepage</title>
    <style>
        .left_grid {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:15%;
}
.center_grid {
    display:inline-flex;
    width:69%;
}
.right_grid {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:15%;
}
#menu {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 10em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
#select_color {

    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 2em;

}
#predefined_color {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
#help {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 10em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
.in_div
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}
    </style>
</head> 
    <body>
    <h1>somepage</h1>
    <div style="width:100%;">
            <div class="left_grid">
                <div id="menu">
                    <h2>Menu</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Color Tester</a></li>
                        <li><a href="help.html">Color Help</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="center_grid">
                <div class="in_div">
                    <div id="select_color">
                        <h2>Select Your Color</h2>
                        <p>Enter the amount of red, green, and blue in your colour.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="predefined_color">
                        <h2>Predefined Colors</h2>
                        <p>You may select one of hte following pre-defined colours to start off with.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right_grid">
            <div id="help">
                <h2>Help</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

you should use float:left for center grid so it can be in one line and float right for last div but i have used float:left for last div and also remember to use **clear:both** whenever you are using float as this will clear the empty space if left.

Also use width option so it will be easier for you. Hope this will help or let me know if there is any issue. Ty

Comment: Thank you for the advice! But how do I center my center column. Now there is no space between the left and center. How do I center it so that only the center column changes its size while left and right column doesn't change size?

Comment: what do you mean? you want to change the center column size on resizing the window or what? i thought you want to make center div in center so i gave width and margin-left and margin-right auto so it will be in center while resizing the window.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to have the middle column at the center. When I resize my window, the center column will start to resize to fit the window size. However, I do not want the left and right columns to resize. I only want to make the center column responsive. Is that possible?

Comment: @zeroquanta, please check my updated code and let me know if its not according to your plan then i will do more changes.

Answer (score 0):

please update css
.center_grid{border: 1px solid black;display: inline-block;margin-left: 20em;width: auto;}

or 
.center_grid{border: 1px solid black;float: left;margin-left: 20em;width: auto;}

Comment: please be in mind you should not center the div by giving one side margin. It will affect the whole structure if anything change.